# No activity Exception when using viewpager and fragments inside fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

Let me describe my project.

I use actionbarsherlock with SlidingMeno from jfeinstein10 . On my main activity i have this sliding menu with a couple of menu item that open Fragments in container. (the same as basic fragment sample in sliding menu example) In one of those fragments i have view-pager with viewpageindicator. View-pager is tied up to FragmentStatePagerAdapter with my fragments. So i have fragments inside fragments. I use getChildFragmentManager() like suggested in the doc, when using fragments inside fragments.

When i select menu item with fragment that hold view-pager for the first time everything work like it should. But when i select some other menu item and then go back to this view-pager fragment i get this exception. 
All other fragments don’t have this problem and in stack trace there is no reference to my code.

https://gist.github.com/4502038

Did any one encounter similar problem or have some idea what is going on.

EDIT: If i use getFragmentManager() instead of getChildFragmentManager() even thou i'm in subfragment. I don't get an exception, but one of the fragments inside viewpager doesn't get recreated after i select viewpager fragment for the second time.

I created a project on github so you guys can take a look.
https://github.com/pzagor2/TestErrorApp

Comment: Had the same scenario. Ended up creating pager adapter like this:
`pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(hostFragment.getChildFragmentManager());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42601 bug.

Uncommenting addToBackStack https://github.com/pzagor2/TestErrorApp/blob/master/MainActivity/src/com/example/myapp/MainActivity.java#L69 , worked for me with your project setup.

You can see the bug in the Google bug report in the first URL.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I fixed the code on github with the help of the links in you post. For now it's working ok. But will report if i found some strange behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I just looked at the GitHub project and it looks like you have not commited your code yet. But I assume your ViewPager is in a fragment itself and the ViewPager is hosting child fragments. If that's so, then I would recommend you test to make sure your FragmentStatePagerAdapter is constructed with the result of getChildFragmentManager().

Comment: I fixed the link to my test project on Git. I Checked and I'm using getChildFragmentManager() when constructing my FragmentStatePagerAdapter.